# Hidden Input Max Value Size

Tags: javascript, php, html

For some reason when I echo inside the `value=""` of a hidden input tag. It for some reason has a max character size. Its much smaller then I need it to be as I need it to put content from my DB into HTML then into Javascript loop.

Please could someone help me find a way of making a input tag allow the ability to write more characters in it. (Possibly unlimited) It isnt encased in any form tag so it's impossible for any vulnerabilitys.

Please note I need this changed so that its cross browser compatible and doesnt need any kind of get or post request.

Thank you.

Edit:

Approach 1: max="99999999999" - Nothing;

Approach 2:

```
<script>

var s1_episodes = JSON.parse(<?= $r['s1_episodes']; ?>);
var s2_episodes = JSON.parse(<?= $r['s2_episodes']; ?>);
var s3_episodes = JSON.parse(<?= $r['s3_episodes']; ?>);

</script>
```

Tried just echoing directly into it like so but nothing seemed to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the property, the correct property name is: `maxlength="9999"` and the default value is 524288

Comment: That fixed half the issue. But now I see that the value is displaying incorrectly. Code: value='<?php echo $s1_episodes; ?>' (Look at this screenshot to see) https://gyazo.com/40c1f8932f671584594de941b1c7ea00 the \" that looks like its ending the value="" is actually a \' the \ isnt doing anything.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape all those `"` characters. Just add a call to addslashes ( string $str )...like this: `value='<?php echo addslashes ($s1_episodes); ?>' `

Comment: still not doing anything

Comment: It works the maxlength and then instead of value=" " i did value=' ' and removed all ' in the value and it fixed it. This sucks that the \ wouldnt fix this.

Comment: Did you add the addslashes function?

Comment: Yes but it wont make a difference since im using value=' ' not =" ".

Comment: Then invert it the other way